# Directory 'X' following -L not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have two warnings for my project in xcode, both don't stop the app running but I want to make sure I build without any warnings.

I recently removed Flurry from my app, and libsimulate and I can't get these messages to stop appearing despite spending many hours searching for answers on StackOverflow and Google.

I know it must be a simple problem to solve. Here is an image to help you understand:
[image: xcode warnings output]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the project or target build settings, search for `libsimulate`. It's being passed as an argument to `-L` somewhere in there, likely by Library Search Paths; edit it out. Then do the same for FlurryLib.

Comment: Thanks, I searched libsimulate and it didn't work, tried flurrylib, found it, deleted it and saw libsimulate there as well. Got rid of it and it builds without any issues. Thanks man!

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same problem after trying out iSimulate.

Comment: Thank you! This has annoyed me for months. I finally decided to search for an answer and here it was.