# Warning message when building iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, simulator

I'm building an iPhone application using the Simulator on "Debug" configuration. I get this warning:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Users/myusername/Documents/iPhoneApps/TestGA/Source/build/GData.build/Debug/GDataFramework.build/Objects-normal/i386' following -L not found
```

I also get this warning:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Users/myusername/Documents/iPhoneApps/TestGA/Source/build/Debug' following -F not found
```

Any insight? How can I fix this? What do these warnings even mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-L` is usually the argument to the linker `ld` to tell it what directories to search in for libraries to link with your code.

The fact that you're getting this warning is not a problem in itself unless you also get errors caused by it (which doesn't appear to be the case). `ld` will happily ignore directories that don't exist.

If you want to get rid of the warnings, you can either:

- create those directories (easiest); or
- find out where in your project settings the particular linker command line settings are being set, and change them (probably the best solution).

Comment: how can I "find out where in" my "project settings the particular linker command line settings are being set, and change them" THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

See this:

[Directory 'X' following -L not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973275/directory-x-following-l-not-found)